# Crop automatically using camera like instagram

Tags: ios, crop, image

I want to take an square picture from the app like instagram.  However I don't know how to do it. I know that the y, the image still has to be cropped, and the camera is capturing the whole image all the time, it's only I am cropping it "live" in the view. When the image is captured, it is still the whole image and still has to be cropped. Only the user doesn't see it happening as it's all done in the background. Once you capture the image with your devices camera, put it﻿ to an instance of a UIImage then write a method that will take that UIIMage and use a CGRefImageContext to resize it  then either overwrite your original UIImage instance if no longer need the original.  I don't get how to do this.  Is there a site that shows how to do this? or is there a easier way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

First, you need to take the photo with the camera, so add this code where you want to take the picture.

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController 
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Then, you need to implement delegate methods. Your class must conform to `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/). In the `imagePickerController:
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method, you can take the taken photo in a `UIImage` with:

```
UIImage *imageTaked = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

If you want, at this point you can take the metadata of the taken photo with

```
info [UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
```

Finally, when you have your photo in a UIImage, you can crop the image as follows:

```
CGFloat x, y, side; //We will see how to calculate those values later.
UIImage* imageCropped;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(x,y,side,side);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageTaked CGImage], cropRect);
imageCropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

So, the important thing here is how to calculate the `cropRect` to cut the centre square of the UIImage. To do that, you can calculate `x`, `y` and `side` as follows:

```
side = MIN(imageTaked.size.width, imageTaked.size.height
x = imageTaked.size.width / 2 - side / 2;
y = imageTaked.size.height / 2 - side / 2;
```

Ok, so, to summarise, all the code inside the `imagePickerController:
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method results in:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *imageTaked = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
    //You can take the metadata here => info [UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];

    UIImage* imageCropped;

    CGFloat side = MIN(imageTaked.size.width, imageTaked.size.height);
    CGFloat x = imageTaked.size.width / 2 - side / 2;
    CGFloat y = imageTaked.size.height / 2 - side / 2;

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(x,y,side,side);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageTaked CGImage], cropRect);
    imageCropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to send your photo to another device, probably the photo will be rotated. That's because Apple uses exif metadata for images, but other platforms don't. To solve this problem, just use this method to set appropriate metadata info:

```
-(UIImage*)getImageWithCorrectFiltersFromOriginalImage:(UIImage *)originalImage
{
    UIImageOrientation orientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
    NSNumber* orientationValue = [originalImage valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"];
    if (orientationValue) {
        orientation = [orientationValue intValue];
    }

    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [originalImage defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [assetRep fullResolutionImage];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:[assetRep scale] orientation:orientation];
}
```

Hope it helps! and let me know if something goes wrong during copy-paste process, it's 2:00AM here, and i'm a zombie man right now!

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply! Just few questions. I want to crop it automatically into a 612x612 like instagram. Where should I change in the code? and also it when i press the camera button in my app it launches the camera but i want to just show the area that is going to be remaining when cropped like the instagram app.  Sorry for bad explanation..

Comment: I understand. If you want to draw a square, you must set the `cameraOverlayView` property of the `pickerController`, after setting the `sourceType`. To crop a square of 612px on each side, you should hardcode the `side` value to 612, but it's not recommended because you don't know the size of the UIImage, and even if you knew it, it could change when iPhone Camera resolution changes.

Comment: Sorry Im a too beginner how am i suppose to set the cameraOverlayView and make it like instagram kinda crop? even i change it to 612 it dosent really change..

Comment: You need to create a view that is a square (that´s another question, if you want to open it in another thread) and after creating that view, and after the `pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;` line, you should make `pickerController.cameraOverlayView = yourNewView;`

Comment: ok I'm confused I want to forget about cameraOverlayView and just focus in cropping to a square that is 320x320 like the allowsediting. I changed the code to  CGFloat x = imageTaked.size.width / 320 - side / 320;
CGFloat y = imageTaked.size.height / 320 - side / 320;

Comment: nice, that's a good decision to start out. Why did you changed the 2 by a 320? the division by 2 was to get the centre point, and from there move half size to the left, and half size to up, to crop the square

Comment: Sorry another problem the crop works when taken in landscape but it does not work in portrait. I want the user to take only in portrait

Comment: Hey @lucaslt89, your code works great here, except my picture is rotated 90 degres counter-clock wise. I know how to turn is using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation on UIImageView, but how to turn the UIImage itself (so I can send it via email for example) ?

Comment: Hey @anthoprotic, i just edited my answer, please take a look at the edit part, and tell me if that method solves your problem. I remember having a lot of problems working with images a year ago, because images were being uploaded to a server and downloaded from android or windows (images were correctly oriented only in iOS and Mac OS).